# Issue with understanding scroll

Tags: jquery

I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dN4S4/3/) to make a smooth scroll

```
$('#up, #down').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var the_id = $(this).attr("href");  

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
       scrollTop : $(the_id).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

and it's execute perfectly but i didn't undestand this line :

```
scrollTop : $(the_id).offset().top
```

Because the scroll is up and down, and i see nothing like 
`scrollDown : $(the_id).offset().down`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called **scrollTop** because it's the distance from the *top* of the page, so there's no need for a *scrollDown*.

The code just rapidly changes the value of **scrollTop** so that the page scrolls smoothly to the given position.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code just indicates the height from the top of your page.

```
scrollTop : $(the_id).offset().top
```

You could add some css to this to start at for example 40px from the top with margin-top: 40px;

It's just 'the top of the page' in easy words.